# Voice is not recognized with Microsoft Speech

Tags: c#, speech-recognition, speech-to-text

I tried implementing a tutorial for Microsoft Speech Recognition. I get no errors but still the voice is not recognized. The Code is like

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;  
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Microsoft.Speech.Recognition;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication3
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    //SpeechRecognizer recognizer;
    SpeechRecognitionEngine sre;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
         sre = new SpeechRecognitionEngine();
         sre.SetInputToWaveFile(@"c:\Test\Colors.wav");

         Console.WriteLine("here");


         // Create a simple grammar that recognizes "red", "green", or "blue".
         Choices colors = new Choices();
         colors.Add(new string[] { "red", "green", "blue" });
         Console.WriteLine("here");

         // Create a GrammarBuilder object and append the Choices object.
         GrammarBuilder gb = new GrammarBuilder();
         gb.Append(colors);

         // Create the Grammar instance and load it into the speech recognition engine.
         Grammar g = new Grammar(gb);
         sre.LoadGrammar(g);

         // Register a handler for the SpeechRecognized event.

         // Start recognition.
         sre.SpeechRecognized +=
           new EventHandler<SpeechRecognizedEventArgs>(sre_SpeechRecognized);


        sre.Recognize();
         Console.WriteLine("here");

    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


    }

    // Create a simple handler for the SpeechRecognized event.
    void sre_SpeechRecognized(object sender, SpeechRecognizedEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("here");

        MessageBox.Show("Speech recognized: " + e.Result.Text);
    }

}
}
```

Kindly help me sort out !! I have no idea why it is not working and am new to C# and Visual Studio

PS: I also get messages in the output window like the following While running the program

```
The thread '<No Name>' (0x674) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread '<No Name>' (0x1ee0) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread '<No Name>' (0xf8) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread '<No Name>' (0x760) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 'vshost.RunParkingWindow' (0x1184) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

Comment: What speech library are you using?  I added a reference to system.speech and your code recognized my wav file.

Comment: i am using Microsoft.speech library... EDIT: I checked the wrong file sorry for that

Comment: Please, do not include information about a language used in a question title unless it wouldn't make sense without it. Tags serve this purpose. Also, do not include IDE tag (Visual Studio) among tags if your question is not directly about it and you just write code in it. Problems with code are seldom connected to a code editor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this code works for me

```
     public partial class MainWindow : Window
        {

            SpeechRecognitionEngine _recognizer;
            SpeechSynthesizer sre = new SpeechSynthesizer();
            int count = 1;

            public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Initialize();
        }

        private void Initialize()
        {
            try
            {
                var culture = new CultureInfo("en-US");
                _recognizer = new SpeechRecognitionEngine(culture);
                _recognizer.SetInputToDefaultAudioDevice();
                _recognizer.LoadGrammar(GetGrammer());
                _recognizer.SpeechRecognized += new EventHandler<SpeechRecognizedEventArgs>(_recognizer_SpeechRecognized);

                _recognizer.RecognizeAsync(RecognizeMode.Multiple);

                sre.SelectVoiceByHints(VoiceGender.Male, VoiceAge.Child);
                sre.Rate = -2;

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(ex.InnerException.Message);
            }
        }

        private static Grammar GetGrammer()
        {

            var choices = new Choices();
            //add custom commands
            choices.Add(File.ReadAllLines(@"Commands.txt"));
            //to add the letters to the dictionary
            choices.Add(Enum.GetNames(typeof(Keys)).ToArray());

            var grammer = new Grammar(new GrammarBuilder(choices));

            return grammer;
        }

        void _recognizer_SpeechRecognized(object sender, SpeechRecognizedEventArgs e)
        {

            string speech = e.Result.Text; 

        //to type letters in open application like notepad
       if (Enum.GetNames(typeof(Keys)).Contains(speech))
        {
            try
            {   //send the string to the application
                SendKeys.SendWait("{" + speech + "}");
            }
            catch (ArgumentException)
            {

            }            
        }  

        //handle custom commands
            switch (speech)
            {

                case "Hello":
                    sre.Speak("Goodmorning ");
                    break;

                case "Notepad":
                    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("Notepad");
                    break;
                case "Maximize":
                    this.WindowState = System.Windows.WindowState.Maximized;
                    break;
                case "Minimize":
                    this.WindowState = System.Windows.WindowState.Minimized;
                    break;
                case "Restore":
                    this.WindowState = System.Windows.WindowState.Normal;
                    break;
                case "Close":
                    Close();
                    break;
            }
        }       
    }
```

You would also need to create a .txt file to load the grammer with the commands each in single line like below

```
Notepad
Close
Minimize
Maximize
Open
Hello
```

Comment: Thanks it worked !! I changed few things like adding the grammar inside the code itself.. also can u suggest me.. is it possible to add dictionary grammar to existing one.. that is if the voice is close .. the application should close.. (as per ur code ) and if the voice is exit then it should type exit.. sth like that..like after opening the notepad if i speak non-user defined grammar .. it should start typing inside the notepad

Comment: @user3260179 Edited the Answer , added the custom logic to type letters in open application like Notepad.I added logic to add all the english letters to the dictionary after adding the Commands.txt.And then sending the letters to the dictionary in the event.This will only type single letter, to add custom words you will need to add them to the commands.txt

Comment: thnks for ur reply... instead of letters how to use prebuilt dictionary grammar .. i tried but the code doesn work.. i cudn upload the code since i don have it now..